# Cannot change password in firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

Here I want to change the old password according to the words I entered, what's wrong?

This is the function I created:

```
const handleChangePassword = async (values) => {
    setLoadingOnSubmit(true);

    const { passwordBaru } = values;


    const user = auth.currentUser;
    const newPassword = passwordBaru;

    try {
      await updatePassword(user, newPassword);

      const foundUser = Object.values(data).find((user) => user.uid === currentUser.uid);

      if (foundUser) {
        const id = Object.keys(data).find((key) => data[key] === foundUser);

        try {
          await axios.patch(`${apiDev}/data-pengguna/${id}.json`, {
            password: newPassword,
          });
          message.success("Password berhasil di ganti");
          navigate('/profile')
        } catch (error) {
          message.error("Gagal mengganti password");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      message.error("Tidak dapat mengganti password");
    } finally {
      setLoadingOnSubmit(false);
    }
  };
```

If the above function is run, the result is like this:
[image]

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "CREDENTIAL_TOO_OLD_LOGIN_AGAIN",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "CREDENTIAL_TOO_OLD_LOGIN_AGAIN",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

example of the request I sent :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the doc, `updatePassword()` "is a security sensitive operation that requires the user to have recently signed in". The `CREDENTIAL_TOO_OLD_LOGIN_AGAIN` error code indicates that the user has to signed in again before being able to all the `updatePassword()` method successfully.

Concretely, you need to ask the user to authenticate again (e.g. shows a "Sign In" form) and then call `reauthenticateWithCredential()`.

See the details in the doc, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#updatepassword) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#reauthenticatewithcredential).